# what is the problem with this Dockerfile, It is not producing /src folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following docker file. Somehow it's not producing any /src folder. /src folder is referred to as the target directory where the .*csproj files will be copied. But once the docker composes up command is used, it refers to the old version of the program.

Then I ended up observing that there is no /src folder and hence no project executable is copied there. I am running aspnet core web api project.

Can somebody point me what's the issue?

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication1.csproj", "WebApplication1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj"
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication1"

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

Following structure I could see in docker container

[image]

Comment: the executable code should be in the app-directory, bot in the src-folder.. Did you verify that?

Answer (score 0):

The provided docker file uses the so called [multi-stage build feature](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) to build and run in different containers, `src` folder is present only in the build/publish one and the application container is run from final which has only `app` folder.

Comment: I need to build multi-staged. I need multiple containers for sure. So what's the solution? Why I am constantly not able to see the latest execution output? It seems some old image code is executing. What should I do to fix this problem.? I need all containers must be up-to-date with the latest source code and have the latest binary image execution.

Comment: @Usman there is a possibility that some docker cache causes problems. Try looking into that (clean caches, force build with no cache, as far as I remember it is possible)

Comment: this is merely a comment than an answer IMHO. The simple answer would be: in a multi-stage env you would need to copy the src-folder to the final stage. However doing this would be pretty weird.

Comment: I would rather ask why does OP need '/src' directory in final image. I.e he doesn't get what is going on in dockerfile.